# checking NAN in typescript

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether a string entered is NAN in typescript. Currently I am doing like

```
if (isNaN(parseInt(input))) return "It's not a number."
```

This works fine if I enter @@@@ or #### but if I enter "444@@@@", this is not working.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with TypeScript, which is merely a typing layer on top of JavaScript and a transpiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` parses *up to* the first non-numeral in the input string, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

In this case, `parseInt("444@@@@") === 444`, and `444` is not `NaN`.

If you want to check if the *entire* string represents a valid number, [use `Number` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```
if (isNaN(Number(input))) return "It's not a number."
```

Alternatively, use the unary plus operator to force a type conversion to `number` (equivalent to calling `Number`):

```
if (isNaN(+input)) return "It's not a number."
```

**EDIT**: Actually, `isNaN` will do a type conversion anyway, so you could just as well call it directly:

```
if (isNaN(input)) return "It's not a number."
```

Comment: if (isNaN(input)) return "It's not a number." This worked. Thanks.